# Problemas em acertar o layout no Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone

Estou tendo dificuldade na seguinte questão. O botão azul na imagem abaixo tem que ficar na altura da cintura da mulher como está no storyboard, mas tem que ser em todos os iPhones (4" pra cima). Como pode ser visto no preview, para cada tamanho de tela o botão fica com tamanho e posição diferente. Para acertar isso eu tenho que usar alguma constraint especifica (sendo q estou usando altura, largura, margem de baixo, horizontal) ou tenho que acertar isso no código?

Obrigado.

[image: iTela xcode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o @danielbmarques falou deve funcionar:

> • leading e trailing nas bordas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> • centralizado vertical:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> • seleciona a constraint e ajusta o *multiplier*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **• resultado esperado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado, muito bem explicado. =D

Answer (score 1):

Pro botão ficar com um tamanho proporcional, em vez de criar constraints pro tamanho dele, cria constraints pro leading e trailing. Assim as bordas dele vão ficar à mesma distância das laterais do iPhone.

Pro alinhamento vertical ficar proporcional, em vez de escolher uma distância, coloca o botão centralizado verticalmente, seleciona a constraint e brinca com o valor do "multiplier" até o botão ficar na posição que você quer.

Edit: Agora que estou pensando não sei se o leading e o trailing vão dar certo… você também pode colocar a largura do botão igual à largura da tela, e aí mexe com o multiplier dessa constraint pra deixar o botão maior ou menor.

Comment: blz, vou tentar. vlw